# Extracting files from sub-folders and merging relevant data into one txt file using R

Tags: r, merge, extract

The situation is this: I have a folder, "A", containing a lot of sub-folders which all have a txt file called "log.txt". Within this "log.txt" there is a passage called "Stats" which states all the data I am interested in.

I want to take this passage, i.e. "States", present in all the "log.txt" within each sub-folders, and the merge it together into one txt file.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please give us an example of the `log.txt` file?

Comment: The log.txt contains a lot of information at different time-points, but what I'm interested occurs at 02:05 and looks like this:

00:02:01.8 autosampler-left: MoveTorqueMode(3, 20 mm, 160 mA, 10 mm/s, 20 s, 0, 10 %, 1 s, True, 0 mA, 0 mA) --> 0.0199985451365468
00:02:02.7 autosampler-left: MoveRelative(0 mm, 0 mm, -2 mm, 33 %, 4, True)
**00:02:05.1 States;06/23/17 15:21:40;Slot1:01;ThroughLoop;3.99040007591248;572.400024414063;15.9099998474121;60.8407402038574;29.5;65.4599990844727;4.02040004730225;0.0333333313465118**
00:02:05.1 pumpa: Stop()

Comment: However, the specific time at which "States" occurs is different from each log.txt, so I can't just extract them according to the time stamp at 02:05:1.